# How can view xml nodes by id?

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product name="civil">
<day>Moonday</day>
    <dataseries>
    <data timepoint="3h"> 03:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="6h"> 06:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="9h"> 09:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="12h"> 12:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="15h"> 15:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="18h"> 18:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="21h"> 21:00 </data>
    <data timepoint="24h"> 00:00 </data>
    </dataseries>
```

How to display alternating nodes? In this way: 3h, 9h, 15h... Something like:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="product/dataseries/data" timepoint="@6h">
```

but this code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
  <xsl:for-each select="product/dataseries/data[@timepoint='6h']>
```

In square brackets there might be also more complex condition (e.g. with or operator, some aritmetics etc.) to select nodes you need.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thanks. I have another problem on this xml file:

I created a menu ul and li in this way:

    <ul>
    <li>
    <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Moonday <img style="width:50px;">
    <xsl:for-each select="product/dataseries/data[@timepoint='6h']">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">/folder1/folder2/<xsl:value-of select="info1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="info2" /><xsl:value-of select="info3" />.png</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each></img></a>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

info1, info2 and info3 have value of zero, then I have an image "000.png" but not appear.

Comment: Be careful about context - in your for-each you are processing "data" element. `<xsl:value-of select="info1" />` returns string value of element `<info1>` located under `<data>` element which is actually processed. But there is no element of this name (in your sample xml) so it return empty string.